# Bind List<T> from class to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to show the Items of a List in a DataGrid. So I did something which should probably work.

First I set the `ItemsSource` of my DataGrid to the List which is located inside a class, and bound the `DataGridTextColumns` of my custom Columns to the Items of the List.

**The Class:**

```
public class Auftrag : INotifyPropertyCanged
{
    private int _id; // ID is an example to show that there is more then `Services`
    private List<Services> _services = new List<Services>();
    [...] // There are more Fields

    [...] // There are more Properties
    public int ID { get; set; } // ID is just an Example. My Properties aren't {get; set;} My properties has all the same structure like `Services` Property
    public List<Services> Services
    {
        get => _services;
        set
        {
            if(_services == value) return;
            _services = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Services");
        }
    }
}
```

The `Services` class contains the Items which you can see in the `XAML` of the `View` where the `DataGridTextColumn` is bind to.

**The ViewModel**

In the ViewModel I created a Property which holds the results from my DataBase:

```
private Auftrag _sAuftrag = new Auftrag();
public Auftrag SAuftrag
{
    get => _sAuftrag;
    set
    {
        if (_sAuftrag == value) return;
        _sAuftrag = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SAuftrag");
    }
}
```

Im reading the DataBase and add the result to the Properties:

```
public async Task<bool> LoadSingleAuftrag(int aID)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Check SQL Connection, Run Query etc.
        [...]
        using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                SAuftrag.AuftragsId = reader["AuftragsID"] as int? ?? default(int);
                SAuftrag.KundenId = reader["KundenID"] as int? ?? default(int);
                SAuftrag.Status = reader["Status"] as string;
                SAuftrag.CreatedDate = reader["ErstelltAm"] as DateTime? ?? default(DateTime);
                SAuftrag.FinishedDate = reader["FertigGestelltAm"] as DateTime? ?? default(DateTime);
                SAuftrag.Services.Add(new Services
                {
                    Servicename = reader["Servicename"] as string,
                    Servicebeschreibung = reader["Servicebeschreibung"] as string,
                    Einzelpreis = reader["Preis"] as double? ?? default(double),
                    Anzahl = reader["Anzahl"] as int? ?? default(int),
                    Preis = Convert.ToDouble(reader["Preis"]) * Convert.ToInt32(reader["Anzahl"])
                });
            }
            // Is working fine, so the Items are sucessfully stored into the `Services` list.
            Debug.WriteLine("Anzahl: " + SAuftrag.Services[0].Anzahl);
            Debug.WriteLine("Einzelpreis: " + SAuftrag.Services[0].Einzelpreis);
            Debug.WriteLine("Gesamtpreis: " + SAuftrag.Services[0].Preis);
        }
    }
}
```

**The View**

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:AuftragViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
[...]
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SAuftrag.Services}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Servicename" Header="Servicename" Binding="{Binding Path=Servicename}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Beschreibung" Header="Beschreibung" Binding="{Binding Path=Servicebeschreibung}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Anzahl" Header="Anzahl" Binding="{Binding Path=Anzahl}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

For me it looks right and should work. But for some Reason I'm getting `InvalidOperationException` Error.

If I commented the DataGrid the application works and it Bindings are visible (for example the `ID` Binding). So there is no `Instance Error`.

Short Version of Error message:
`An ItemsControl is not consistent with its element source. For more information, see the inner exception.`

May the Properties of the `Services` class causes the Error?:

**Services Class**

```
[..]
private double _preis;
private double _einzelpreis;
[..]
public double Preis
{
    get => _preis;
    set
    {
        if (_preis == value) return; // Possible loss of precision while rounding values warning
        _preis = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Preis");
    }
}
public double Einzelpreis
{
    get => _einzelpreis;
    set
    {
        if (_einzelpreis == value) return; // Possible loss of precision while rounding values warning
        _einzelpreis = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Einzelpreis");
    }
}
```

**View.CodeBehind**

In the Code behind, I call a Method to Load data:

```
private readonly AuftragViewModel _viewModel;

public AuftragsInfo(int aID)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _viewModel = (AuftragViewModel) DataContext;
    LoadAuftrag(aID);
}

public async void LoadAuftrag(int aID)
{
    if (!await _viewModel.LoadSingleAuftrag(aID))
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: As a note, type and property name may be equal, like `public Auftrag Auftrag { get; set; }`.

Comment: The `S` stands for `Single`. :)

Comment: As another note, it usually looks odd when you mix languages in your code. Consider using english identifier names only.

Comment: Yea that's a quirk I have. I mix german with english. The members in Services is the same structure like the other Properties (`private type _property; public type Property {get => _property; set ...}`)

Comment: And you're sure it's not one of the property getters that throws the exception? We can only guess what's wrong with your code...

Comment: I added a short version of my `Services` class where may the Error can be, because I got a warning there (from ReCharper).

Comment: @Pielroja, please create a [mcve]. *Complete* is important word here. Binding use `Binding="{Binding Path=Servicename}"`, for example. posting code for `Preis` doesn't help. also `InvalidOperationException` should include some message about error. what is it?

Comment: @ASh I added some Code, but I don't think that there's a problem. The short version of the error message is `An ItemsControl is not consistent with its element source. For more information, see the inner exception.`

Comment: I cannot see inner exception from here. But it doesn't look like properties of Services cause the trouble. Since list changes dynamically, replace `List` with `ObservableCollection`

Comment: I installed English language pack to show you the english error (because mine is german) but it's still in german the rest of VS is english but the error is in german. GG So i just used Google Translate for it and uploaded the inner exception to hastebin:
https://hastebin.com/ivoyukozin.sql

Comment: Couple of suggestions, In ViewModels always use ObservableCollection instead of List. Also once ViewMdoel is loaded make sure the Datacontext is reassigned with the updated ViewModel.

Comment: @Viju Why using ObservableCollection instead of List<T> ? I though List<T> is faster.

Comment: @Pielroja , Take a look at this link. Mainly ObservableCollection implements INotifyPropertyChanged which is crictical for 2 way binding. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42536/List-vs-ObservableCollection-vs-INotifyPropertyCha

Answer (score 0):

@ASh wrote in the comments to try out `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`.
I don't know why, but after changing the `List` to `ObservableCollection` and adding the items via `Dispatcher`, it's working.

So if someone have this kind of error in the future too, dont use `List` anymore. I guess it's the best way to use `ObservableCollection`.

Thanks to @ASh.